# React Ant Design table filtering not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filtering, antd

I am trying to implement the ant design table filtering functionality within my react component, however, I am having an issue displaying the actual values of the data I am trying to filter through. The data is populated in the array (this.state.data) and the drop down displays the actual length of data in the array but no actual visible data/values of the names I am trying to display. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    const registeredUsersColumns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "Name",
    key: "1",
    filters: this.state.data,
    onFilter: (value, record) => record.Name.indexOf(value) === 0,
  }]
```

Comment: what your data array looks like ?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal [{
FCR_EmailAddress: "testuser92@gmail.com"
FCR_PhoneNumber: "17248597817"
Id: 1
Name: "Test User"
OIC_Name: "jdshd5"
OIC_StaffID: 123
PNC_Id: "hk562"
}]

Comment: this code makes no sense. can you explain it ? record.Name.indexOf(value) === 0,

Comment: @MohammadFaisal It's from ant designs table filtering documentation. Record represents the object within the array index and I believe value represents the dataIndex I am targeting "Name". Here's the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/yttnl

Answer (score 0):

OnFilter must return this value : `record[indexOftheFiltringColumn]`

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the desired behavior change `.indexOf` to `.includes`:

```js
onFilter: (value, record) => record.name.includes(value),

// and 

onFilter: (value, record) => record.address.includes(value),
```

Fixed CodeSanbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-table-filtering-fix-s26xg?file=/index.js:1212-1277).